# Fetch 'xhr' response when "Send" button is clicked in gmail

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am making CRM for Gmail.

I want to get the unique "email id" in my chrome extension from the "xhr" response when "Send" button is clicked. I have not overridden any gmail functionality.

My plan is to use that email id to get the email using gmail api.

Is there any other way by which I can get the email data when the email is sent and save it in my system?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a week, I got a way to get the unique emailID.

When email is sent, a link is displayed - "Your message has been sent. **View message**".

View Message is a link. If you inspect this link, you will get a span element. It has an attribute 'param', which contains the emailID.

I fetched emailID from there and passed it in request to gmail API to get the email data.

I know it is not a permanant solution, but working for me as of now. 
If someone knows some other solution, please share.