# Implement interceptor concept in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, angular-http-interceptors

I am working on a chrome extension.

I want to implement interceptor concept (that of angular) in chrome extension.

My requirement is all the requests sent from chrome extension must pass through the interceptor. If the session is expired, then the form data should be stored in the local storage and then the when the user will log in again, then at that time the old session will be resumed i.e., the form data will be fetched from the local storage and the request will be sent automatically.

How should I proceed? Can I use `chrome.webRequest`? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are going on the right direction `chrome.webRequest` is what you are looking for.

If you are not dealing with response data than it is pretty easy. 
check this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest (google official docs) it is pretty state forward, but this Apis are only available on background page

this link explains about background page https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

dont forget to add the permissions `webRequest` and `<all_urls>`(as I have understand that you are not interested in particular website or else use that website address insteed of `1)

If you need to get the response body then you need to attach the debugger.

Example check this how it intercepts the request and response headers https://github.com/vitvad/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Soon I will be adding whole demo extension here

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try the implementation using webRequest. You also gave hint for another query in which I need the response body of a http request I make. If possible, please go to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093334/fetch-xhr-response-when-send-button-is-clicked-in-gmail).

Comment: Sure @PallaviGoyal I will give you a working demo soon, for now, you can search  for `how to attach chrome debugger from extension` . If it resolved your issue can you please accept my answer